# Intuition for semistable points on a $G$-variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, geometric-invariant-theory

I'm reading some lecture notes on the relationship between GIT quotients and symplectic reduction, and came across the definition of a semistable point. For completeness, I will re-write it below:

> Let $G$ be a complex reductive algebraic group and $(X,\mathcal{O}_X(1))$ a polarized $G$-variety. If we form the ring $$R(X) = \bigoplus_{d\geq 0} H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(d)),$$ the action on $X$ induces an action on $R(X)$, so we have the (sub)ring of invariants $R(X)^G$. Then a point $x\in X$ is called semistable if $s(x) \neq 0$ for some $s\in R(X)^G_{>0}$.

I frankly do not have any intuition for this definition. I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921387/two-equivalent-definitions-of-git-semistable-points)  but the discussion there wasn't particularly helpful. Is there a Hartshorne-level way of thinking about this that lends some intuition for why this is a desirable property (or even why its called semistable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a satisfactory answer at the bottom of page 10 in the notes "Introduction to actions of algebraic groups" by Michel Brion. Found at the link [here](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~mbrion/notes_luminy.pdf).